# iOS thread collision on main queue

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have cells coming in with the `insertItemsAtIndexPath` method, and when I try to access my AVFoundation controller class, I get a crash half the time. I have a feeling it is thread collision on the main thread, and tried to use logic to help, and that did not solve the issue.

I've been reading up on mutex and semaphores, and I was wondering what would be your suggestion how to handle the process above. Essentially, I am trying to get the `[self presentViewController:myAVFoundationController]` not to collide with a for loop that includes `dispatch_asyn(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{ [_collectionView insertItemAtIndexPath:@[indexPath]] };`

I'm looking in to @synchronized() at the moment, however it seems there are many options via [the documentation I am looking at](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html). Of the options: NSOperation/Queue, mutex, semaphore, and others how to implement thread safety on the main queue.

Comment: what does the crash log say?

Comment: @PatrickGoley it's an assertion crash, I think it's solved by adding the UI updates to `@synchronized([NSOperationQueue mainQueue])`

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but you'll need to post more code to get any real help.  Especially, you should show code pertaining to going off the main thread and back on, any crash logs you're getting, and why you think the issue is related to `presentViewController:`.  As it is, your post is too vague for anyone to really help you.

Comment: @AaronBrager was looking for feedback what others use to manage events on main thread moreso than anything else. Thank you for your thoughtfulness.

Comment: Have a look at -findSymbolsInDocumentContents to see how I do a background operation that jumps to the foreground to update the UI. https://github.com/abhibeckert/Dux/blob/master/Dux/DuxPHPLanguage.m

Comment: While you could pursue any of the synchronizing techniques (`@synchronized` directive, `NSLock`, etc.), given that you're already dispatching the UI update to the main queue, if you put your model updates in that same block dispatched to the main queue, that will generally solve it, too. So you can have background queue do the slow/expensive stuff on the background queue to local vars, and dispatch the updating of the model and the UI back to the main queue). Be wary about disconnecting the model updates from the UI updates, or else you can have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have threading problems as long as anything related to your UI, and anything that writes to any value that is related to your UI is wrapped in `dispafch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)`;

Pause execution by adding an "all exceptions" breakpoint in the debugger and then look at the stack trace of all threads.

If the main thread is the only one doing anything, then you don't have a threading problem. Only the main thread can touch anything related to the user interface, and any properties you have that are needed on the main thread should be set there. Lastly, do not share mutable objects between threads. Make a copy of it (copies are immutable by default) before giving I to the other thread.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful advice I will remember. Just in the case above, the dispatch_async() was performing independently of the other process that also updated UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have found luck with `@synchronized`, such as the following:

```
@synchronized([NSOperationQueue mainQueue]) { 
    [self uiUpdate]; 
    }
```

Comment: Do not use @synchronised. It's slow and will probably be deprecated one day. Use GCD instead, unless you need to run on iOS 4

Comment: the only way I could think to do it with GCD was to apply dispatch_sync() to one of the processes, and as expected it would lock/freeze the main thread indefinitely. I tried using dispatch_group_wait() to no avail, however, I think you are absolutely spot on that perhaps semaphores would be a much better solution. alas, I have to wait and see how my efforts there will surface.

Comment: dispatch_sync (or preferably dispatch_async if possible, it's faster and will not deadlock) are the correct tools to solve your problem. There must be something you're doing wrong that you didn't show us.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert those methods, unfortunately, did not work when attempting to push/present controller with AVFoundation whilst the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{ [_collectionView insertItemAtIndexPath:@[indexPath]] };` was in function. Pushing to other controllers did not cause error, and it well may have been different given time spent to address other areas in the program. Currently, the push/present to controller with AVFoundation is working well-- happy to report no crash on multiple attempts after inserting the code, and I will look more deep in to this issue in the near future.

Comment: A couple parameters changes highlighted @synchronized() was not the solution, and indeed, I just found the solution by making the async insertItems process, synchronous, as you mentioned. Thank you, accepted your answer as the solution, and +1.